# Updating Data in the gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview in VS 2005. The grid is displayed in textboxes, so the user can edit.

```
  <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="50">
      <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtSmall" runat="server" Width="45px" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Small") %>' OnTextChanged="TxtSmallChanged"> </asp:TextBox>                                                          
      </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
  <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="50">
       <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtMedium" runat="server" Width="45px" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Medium") %>' OnTextChanged="TxtMediumChanged"> </asp:TextBox>                                                          
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
 <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width = "50">
       <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:TextBox ID="txtTotal" runat="server" Width="45px" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Total") %>'> </asp:TextBox>
             </ItemTemplate>                                                     
       </asp:TemplateField>
```

Whenever the textbox txtsmall or txtmedium changes(numbers), the Textbox txttotal has to get updated as total of both in txtSmall and txtmedium. I am using a function TxtSmallChanged when text in it is changed. How do i write the codebehind function to update the txtTotal. I hope i am clear. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Just a suggestion but consider using client script for something like this.

Comment: @BalaR Thanks Bala, but can you please be specific?! You mean to say Javascript?

Comment: You need to run a javascript, something like:
onUpdate { txtTotal.Text = txtSmall.Text + txtMedium.Text; }

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. Let me try that! Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

 Set Autopostback=true

```
 protected void txtSmall_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox t = (TextBox)sender;
        GridViewRow r = (GridViewRow)t.NamingContainer;
        Txtchanged(r.RowIndex);
    }

    protected void txtMedium_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox t = (TextBox)sender;
        GridViewRow r = (GridViewRow)t.NamingContainer;
        Txtchanged(r.RowIndex);
    }

    private void Txtchanged(int row_index)
    {
        TextBox t1 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[row_index].Cells[0].FindControl("txtSmall");
        TextBox t2 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[row_index].Cells[0].FindControl("txtMedium");
        TextBox t3 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[row_index].Cells[0].FindControl("txtTotal");
        t3.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(t1.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(t2.Text)).ToString();

    }
```

You Can update database with new values in the Txtchanged

Comment: I tried making this with javascript, to avoid the refresh (you don't need AJAX). But I can't figure out how to get the Id's of the textboxes...